# Haskell to LLVM bitcode

Tags: haskell, ghc, llvm-ir

I'm trying to reproduce the Haskell compilation in [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380547/generate-llvm-ir-from-haskell-code)
similar to what it said in that post:

```
ghc -fllvm quicksort.hs
```

Here is quicksort.hs:

```
module Test where

quicksort [] = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where
        lesser = filter (< p) xs
        greater = filter (>= p) xs
```

However I get the following message that llvm is too new:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Test             ( quicksort.hs, quicksort.o )
You are using a new version of LLVM that hasn't been tested yet!
We will try though...
opt: /tmp/ghc6115_0/ghc6115_0.ll:12:6: error: unexpected type in metadata definition
!0 = metadata !{metadata !"top"}
     ^
```

Now this is a strange because I'm using llvm 3.8.0. What's going on here?
Thanks!

Comment: For me it works. I think I use `llvm` 4.0 (on Windows). I get the message `You are using an unsupported version of LLVM! Currently only 3.9 is supported.` but it works.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent, I'm on Ubuntu (14.04.5) but it's weird they say 3.8.0 is too new, and they only support 3.9.0 :]]

Comment: Maybe that depends onn the GHC version ? I'm using 8.2.1.

Comment: The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2

Comment: [ you'll need to install LLVM 3.7](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_0_2.html)

Comment: Why don't use stack ? It allows to choose the GHC version.